# How can I test the page title with Capybara 2.0?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

Trying to test that page contains `<title>My Title</title>` with:

```
# spec/features/reports_spec.rb
require 'spec_helper'

feature "Archive Management" do
  subject { page }

  describe "Index Page" do
    before(:all) { 10.times { FactoryGirl.create(:randomreport) } }
    after(:all) { Report.delete_all }

    describe "when no search terms present" do
      before { visit reports_path }

      it { should have_selector('title', text: 'My Title') } # <= Fails w/Capybara 2.0
      it { should have_selector('title') }                   # <= passes
      it { should have_text('My Title') }                    # <= passes
      it { should have_selector('h2', text: "Welcome") }     # <= passes
    end
  end
end
```

Error message:

```
 Failure/Error: it { should have_selector('title', text: base_title) }
 Capybara::ExpectationNotMet:
   expected to find css "title" with text "My Title" but there were no matches. Also found "", which matched the selector but not all filters.
```

I know I'm overlooking the painfully obvious but can't figure out what it is? Are `<title>` tags no longer considered 'selectors'?!? Or...?!?

**Edit (debugger info)**:

If I drop down into the debugger as cleverly suggested by @shioyama it is clear that the page.body contains `<title>My Title</title>`. The same page.body that contains `<h2>Welcome to My Title Project</h2>` and passes!

It appears to find the `<title>`...`</title>` tag but not `My Title` within it. But it does find `My Title` later in the page within `<a href=\"/\" class=\"brand\">My Title</a>` and/or in `<h2>Welcome to The My Title Project</h2>`:

```
(rdb:1) p page
#<Capybara::Session>
(rdb:1) p page.body
"<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html>\n<head>\n<title>My Title</title>\n
<meta content='research, report, technology' name='keywords'>\n<meta 
content='Some Project' name='description'>\n<link href=\"/assets/application.css\"
...
</head>\n<body>\n<header class='navbar navbar-fixed-top 
navbar-inverse'>\n<div class='navbar-inner'>\n<div class='container'>\n
<a href=\"/\" class=\"brand\">My Title</a>\n<div class='pull-right'>\n
<ul class='nav'>\n<li><a href=\"/about\">About</a></li>\n<li><a href=\"/help\">Help</a>
</li>\n</ul>\n<form accept-charset=\"UTF-8\" action=\"/reports\" 
class=\"navbar-search\" method=\"get\"><div style=\"margin:0;padding:0;display:inline\">
<input name=\"utf8\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"&#x2713;\" /></div>\n
<input class=\"search-query\" id=\"query\" name=\"query\" 
placeholder=\"Search\" type=\"text\" />\n</form>\n\n</div>\n</div>\n</div>\n</header>\n\n
<div class='container'>\n<div class='hero-unit center'>\n<h1>My Title</h1>\n
<h2>Welcome to The My Title Project</h2>\n<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur 
adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
...
```

What else could I try in the debugger to figure out why have_selector?('title', text: ...) is failing?

**So, what is the proper way to test for a title in Capybara 2.0?**

Comment: What if you try `should have_xpath("//title[contains(.,'#{base_title}')]")` ?

Comment: @shioyama - That works and passes!  I'm still interested in finding out why `have_selector` is *not* working for me though...

Comment: Hmm... this xpath is testing that the `<title>` tag *contains* the text. Perhaps there is whitespace or newlines that are tripping up the selector? I thought it ignored those, but I could be wrong.

Comment: I've updated my answer, see below.

Comment: OK, seems it's a known 'issue' with 2.0... https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/issues/844

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I had the same issues when I upgraded to Capybara 2.0, and managed to solve them by creating the following custom RSpec matcher using [`Capybara.string`](http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara#string-class_method):

**spec/support/utilities.rb**

```
RSpec::Matchers::define :have_title do |text|
  match do |page|
    Capybara.string(page.body).has_selector?('title', text: text)
  end
end
```

Now, in a spec file where `subject { page }`, I can use:

```
it { should have_title("My Title") }
it { should_not have_title("My Title") }
```

As an aside, the conversation on this question was extremely helpful in getting me to this answer, so thank you!

#### Update 1:

If you don't want to create a custom RSpec matcher, thanks to [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14921891/567863) by user [dimuch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1416723/dimuch) I now know that you can call `have_selector` directly on [`page.source`](http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Session#source-instance_method) (aliased `page.body`) to test for non-visible DOM elements:

```
it "should show the correct title" do
  page.source.should have_selector('title', text: 'My Title')
end
```

or where `subject { page }`:

```
its(:source) { should have_selector('title', text: 'My Title') }
```

### Update 2:

From Capybara 2.1, there are built-in `have_title`/`has_title?` matchers, negating the need for the custom RSpec matcher in this answer.  Furthermore, the `its(:source) { ... }` tests described in Update 1 seem to break under Capybara 2.1; I've confirmed the `have_title`/`has_title?` work as expected, so it's probably best to go with the following syntax if you plan on upgrading:

When `subject { page }`:

```
it { should have_title("My Title") }
it { should_not have_title("My Title") }
```

When using `expect` syntax within an `it`/`scenario` block:

```
expect(page).to have_title("My Title")
expect(page).to_not have_title("My Title")
```

Comment: thanks for your solution ... I am also testing the update action but I am getting a "NoMethodError: undefined method put" ... Any suggestions? ... Thanks.

Comment: @railguage48, you might want to consider asking a separate question as there's no way we can tell what your issue is without a lot more details.

Comment: Per @Paul Fioravanti Update 2, I use the following with Capybara 2.1 (and RSpec 2.12):
`expect(response.body).to have_title('my title')`
And this works fine for me.

Comment: `page.should have_selector('title', text: 'My Title', visible: false)` will work too. In fact passing `visible: false` works with any selector where you need to match hidden content. So while `has_title` is more elegant for matching title, if you need to match other hidden content, use `visible: false`. Using expect syntax: `expect(response.body).to have_selector('title', text: 'my title', visible: false)`

Answer (score 3):

Capybara 2.1 changed its support for querying the title element. So using have selector in to query for the title element in the head of the html doc in this fashion will fail "page.should have_selector('title', :text => 'Some text'). From what i understand the preferred method in capybara 2.1 new API is to use "page.should have_title('Some text')" to query the title element should work.

Answer (score 3):

i ran into the same issue when upgrading capybara from version 1.x to > 2.0

The problem is that Capybara ignores invisible text in its matchers. The cleanest way to address this issue is to use the `:visible => false` option on finders.

e.g.

`it { should have_selector('title', text: 'My Title', visible: false) }`

Another (global) option is to set:

`Capybara.ignore_hidden_elements = false`

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem only when using 'shared_examples_for', maybe because of other changes. I also noticed that when I placed

```
<title>My Title</title>
```

in the body of the page (where it doesn't belong and won't render), the test passed. Not a good thing!

This worked:

```
it{should have_title("My Title")}
```

(capybara 2.1.0,
launchy 2.3.0,
nokogiri 1.5.9,
rspec 2.13)

Answer (score 1):

I see two possible issues here:

1. The `<title>` tag is present on the page but the text `My Title` is somewhere else on the page, not within the tag. That would explain why the other tests pass: there is a `<title>` tag on the page so `have_selector('title')` passes, and there is the `My Title` text on the page so `have_text(base_title)` passes.
2. The `<title>` tag contains the text `My Title` as well as something else, which would also explain the results you see: there is a `<title>` tag on the page so `have_selector('title')` passes, and there is the text `My Title` so the `have_text(base_title)` also passes, however the `text` option in `have_selector` is strict, therefore it will fail if it finds a string which does not exactly equal `My Title`.

You can check the latter of these two possibilities using the xpath selector: `should have_xpath("//title[contains(.,'#{base_title}')]")`. If that passes, then you probably have some whitespace or newlines around your title text which are tripping `have_selector` up (I thought it ignored those, but I could be wrong).

Hope that helps.

Comment: ya but...I can verify that `<title>My Title</title>` exists on the page being tested and have done so with `save_and_open_page` so there *is* text between the <title> tags.

Comment: I can remove `base_title` so that it's not a distraction and replace it with `'My Title'` and it still won't pass. There is no unnecessary white space that I can see (unless for some inexplicable reason there are control characters in there that are causing test to fail). I think this is a semantic/syntax issue relating to changes with Capybara 2.0 but I can't figure it out...

Comment: Oh I realized now that I'm using Capybara 1.1.2 in the project where I use `have_selector` in the way that you have here, so perhaps you're right.

Comment: This is just getting weirder but I find if I replace `subject { page }` with `subject { page.body }` then all specs pass...which is ironic because the `<title>...` tag is w/in the `<head>` tag and not the `<body>`!?!  OR, i can replace `should ...` with `body.should ...` and it'll pass. What the hell is going on and why isn't this documented? I'm too big of an RSpec newb to wrap my head around it all...

Comment: The `body` in `page.body` is not the HTML body (i.e. what's in the `<body>` tags), but the body of the *response* (a string), which includes the full HTML. So that's not really weird. `page` itself is an instance of `Capybara::Session`, so really a totally different type of object.

Comment: p.s. I've tested some code using `has_selector?` in the console and I find that the `:text` option is actually checking that the content in the selected tags *contains* the text (does not have to be an exact match). So I can't really explain the behaviour you're observing.

Comment: Sorry, my comment above was regarding capybara 1.1.2, I'm currently trying to update to see if I can isolate the issue. Have a read of this if you haven't already: http://alindeman.github.com/2012/11/11/rspec-rails-and-capybara-2.0-what-you-need-to-know.html

Comment: Update: I've now confirmed that what I observed above in the console applies to Capybara 2.0.1 as well. So I don't know what's going on in your case, but I'd suggest adding `debugger` to your Gemfile, and a line `require 'debugger'; debugger'` inside your test. Then you can experiment, e.g. `p page.has_selector?('title')` etc. (`p` = print).

Answer (score 0):

I know this has an accepted answer already, but for what it's worth, you can do the following, in less lines of code:

```
title = first("head title").native.text
expect(title).to == "What you expect it to match"
```

This allows access to the native driver element; further, since Capybara 2.0 ignores invisible text (title is invisible except to the browser), you would need this (or a similar workaround) to satisfy this case. (See https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/issues/863)