# How to write a spec for something like @post.tags.map?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have a many-to-many association between a  **Post** and a **Tag** model.
Then, I have the following in my post view:

**posts/show.html.erb:**

```
<p><%= raw @post.tags.map { |t| link_to t.name, tag_path(t.name) }.join(', ') %></p>
```

This is the spec I wrote:

**post_pages_spec.rb:**

```
  describe "show page" do
    let!(:post) { FactoryGirl.create(:post, user:        user,
                                            title:       "Lorem",
                                            content:     "Lorem ipsum",
                                            category_id: category.id,
                                            tag_list:     "#{tag.id}") }

    before do 
      sign_in user
      visit post_path(post)
    end

    it { should have_selector('h1',       text: post.title) }
    it { should have_selector('title',    text: post.title) }
    it { should have_link(post.user.name, href: user_path(user)) }
    it { should have_selector('p',        text: post.content) }
    it { should have_selector('p',        text: post.category.name) }
    it { find("p").should have_content(post.tags.map { |t| t.name }.join(", ")) }
    .
    .
    .
```

I'm getting this error:

> Failures:
>
> 1) Post pages show page 
>        Failure/Error: it { find("p").should have_content(post.tags.map { |t| t.name }.join(", ")) }
>          expected there to be content "1, tag28" in "Lorem ipsum"
>        # ./spec/requests/post_pages_spec.rb:28:in `block (3 levels) in '

The code works in the real site, but as you can see, the spec is failing. What's the right way of writing this spec?

**EDIT:**

An example of the post model (just in case):

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  include ActionView::Helpers

  attr_accessible :title, :content, :category_id, :tag_list

  has_many :taggings, :dependent => :destroy  
  has_many :tags, :through => :taggings
  .
  .
  .
```

**Output from live site:**

```
  <p><a href="/tags/inkscape">inkscape</a>, <a href="/tags/gimp">gimp</a></p>
```

Comment: include the actual `page.body`, the failure is just saying the found element has the content "Lorem ipsum", so it could be a matter of finding the wrong element out of many possible reasons

Comment: @prusswan Sorry, what do you mean by including page.body?

Comment: `page.body` is the actual html content as received by the test. It is common to do `page.body.should have_content ...` and you can print it to check for any missing elements

Comment: @prusswan hey I did that: `it { page.body.should have_content(post.tags.map { |t| t.name }.join(", ")) }` the test passed. So I'm a bit confused. How should I fix the test to make it pass in a "conventional" way?

Comment: Maybe this is related? https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/issues/844 `have_content` is an alias for `have_text`.

Comment: @prusswan testing `find('p').should ...` I found that if you have more than one match on the page, Capybara returns an error: `Capybara::Ambiguous Exception: Ambiguous match, found 3 elements matching css "p"`, so I think we can rule that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

From the comment thread, we've figured out that replacing the `find` with a simple `have_selector` passes:

```
it { should have_selector('p', text: post.tags.map { |t| t.name }.join(", ")) }
```

It's not clear why `find('p').should have_content(...)` does not work. I've tested the same type of view (with `<p>` tags wrapping a list of links) and found that the `find('p').should ...` pattern works fine, so something funny is happening in your code. It may or may not be related to the issue with `have_content` in Capybara 2.0, which I discuss below.

If anyone has any ideas please share them! This is the best I can offer.

**Original answer**

The new text matcher in Capybara 2.0 [excludes content that is not visible](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/issues/844), producing somewhat [unintuitive results](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/issues/844#issuecomment-10810708):

```
it { should have_selector('title', text: 'Some Title') } # <= fails
it { should have_selector('title') }                     # <= passes
it { should have_text('Some Title') }                    # <= passes
```

And, relevant to the case in this question, [this](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/issues/844#issuecomment-10595225):

```
find("title").should have_content("some text") # <= fails
```

See also this post: [How can I test the page title with Capybara 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13573525/rspec-capybara-2-0-tripping-up-my-have-selector-tests/13574731#13574731)

If `page.body.should ...` is working but `page.should ...` (or in another form, `subject { page} ; it { should ... }`) isn't, then perhaps this is the issue. Note that `page.body` is an HTML string, whereas `page` is a `Capybara::Session`, they're totally different, although it seems in Capybara 2.0 at least you can run your expectations against either. I think `page.body` includes *all* HTML, hence bypassing the visibility issue.

Comment: Thanks, so `page.body` is the only way to go? Or is there a better way of writing that line of spec?

Comment: I don't really know, to be honest. You'll see in that other SO answer that we spent a lot of time trying to figure out what in the world was going on, only to find that it's a new quirk of Capybara. Probably best to post a question to that github thread.

Comment: so Capybara 2.0 is final already? I pity the newcomers (and others) who will be tripped up by the changes

Comment: @alexchenco It's still a bit suspicious to me though that your other tests pass, so I suspect this may actually not be the cause. What if you change that spec to: `it { should have_selector('p', text: post.tags.map { |t| t.name }.join(", ")) }`?

Comment: @prusswan not really sure, I only started using it because someone else was asking about it in a SO question. But I think this change to `have_text`/`have_content` is pretty unintuitive. I really wish there were better documentation...

Comment: @shioyama the test passes with that code too. Mmmm...strange I'm confused. What were you trying to test with that code?

Comment: @alexchenco Trying to test if it's the `find('p')` that is tripping up the test, and it seems that it is. Not sure about the cause though. Mind if I post this as an answer? Is there any particular reason you chose to go with a `find` instead of using `have_selector` like you did for the other tests?

Comment: @shioyama Sure, I would ike to see your answer. I think I was trying to use `have_content` to see if it worked, and to make it more specific I added `find('p')`.

Comment: @alexchenco I've tested a similar view (with a list of links) and I find that `find('p').should have_content(...)` works, so there's something funny going on in your code.

Comment: @alexchenco Ok updated my answer. I suggest you add `gem debugger` to your Gemfile and stick a `require 'debugger'; debugger` in your `it` block there, run the spec and then when it stops at that line, just try playing around in the debugger. That's how I usually figure these things out.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the `it { ... }` construct for your specs, `it` should be defined at the top like:

```
subject { page }
```

I can't remember what is the default subject for request specs, but normally I would define `subject` as described.

Comment: I do have `subject { page }` at the top of my file.

Comment: in that case, do a check of what is returned by `find('p')`. You can try fixing it by passing more specific arguments to `find`, or do without it altogether (just using page.body)