# GET 'home' should have the right title Chapter 4 of Michael Hartl's tutorials

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Rspec test should pass but fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14122225/rspec-test-should-pass-but-fails)

Why am I getting this error?

C:\Sites\sample_app>rspec
?[32m.?[0m?[31mF?[0m?[32m.?[0m?[31mF?[0m?[32m.?[0m?[31mF?[0m

Failures:

1) PagesController GET 'home' should have the right title
     ?[31mFailure/Error:?[0m ?[31mresponse.should have_selector("title",?[0m
     ?[31mNoMethodError:?[0m
       ?[31mundefined method `has_selector?' for #<ActionController::TestResponse:0x4162ce0>?[0m
?[36m     # ./spec/controllers/pages_controller_spec.rb:14:in`block (3 levels) in '?[0m

2) PagesController GET 'contact' should have the right title
     ?[31mFailure/Error:?[0m ?[31mresponse.should have_selector("title",?[0m
     ?[31mNoMethodError:?[0m
       ?[31mundefined method `has_selector?' for #<ActionController::TestResponse:0x3eab898>?[0m
?[36m     # ./spec/controllers/pages_controller_spec.rb:27:in`block (3 levels) in '?[0m

3) PagesController GET 'about' should have the right title
     ?[31mFailure/Error:?[0m ?[31mresponse.should have_selector("title",?[0m
     ?[31mNoMethodError:?[0m
       ?[31mundefined method `has_selector?' for #<ActionController::TestResponse:0x3f1ccb0>?[0m
?[36m     # ./spec/controllers/pages_controller_spec.rb:41:in`block (3 levels) in '?[0m

Finished in 5.15 seconds
?[31m6 examples, 3 failures?[0m

Failed examples:

?[31mrspec ./spec/controllers/pages_controller_spec.rb:12?[0m ?[36m# PagesController GET 'home' should have the right title?[0m
?[31mrspec ./spec/controllers/pages_controller_spec.rb:25?[0m ?[36m# PagesController GET 'contact' should have the right title?[0m
?[31mrspec ./spec/controllers/pages_controller_spec.rb:39?[0m ?[36m# PagesController GET 'about' should have the right title?[0m

Randomized with seed 501

> Application_helper.rb

module ApplicationHelper

```
# Retrun a title on a per-page basic.
def title
    base_title = "Ruby on Railys tut sample app"
    if @title.nil?
        base_title
    else
        "#{base_title} | #{@title}"
    end
end
```

end

> Pages_controller_spec.rb
>
> require 'spec_helper'
>
> describe PagesController do
>   render_views
>
> describe "GET 'home'" do
>   it "should be successful" do
>   get 'home'
>   response.should be_success
>   end
>
> it "should have the right title" do
>   get 'home'
>   response.should have_selector("title",
>   :content => "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | Home")
>   end
>   end
>
> describe "GET 'contact'" do
>   it "should be successful" do
>   get 'contact'
>   response.should be_success
>   end
>
> it "should have the right title" do
>   get 'contact'
>   response.should have_selector("title",
>   :content =>
>   "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | Contact")
>   end
>   end
>
> describe "GET 'about'" do
>   it "should be successful" do
>   get 'about'
>   response.should be_success
>   end
>
> it "should have the right title" do
>   get 'about'
>   response.should have_selector("title",
>   :content =>
>   "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | About")
>       end
>     end
>   end

If you need something else just add and thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need the base_title method to return the exact string you are testing for.  In this case "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App".  Currently you have it setting the title as "Ruby on Railys tut sample app".

Comment: still got the same error

Comment: gem install 'nokogiri' # required for installing webrat gem
gem install 'webrat'

>in #{RAILS_ROOT}/Gemfile:
>group :test do
>gem 'webrat'
>end

>in #{RAILS_ROOT}/spec/spec_helper.rb (at the end of file):
># Webrat configuration
>Webrat.configure do |config|
>config.mode = :rails
.end And it works now! I will answer my own question in 7 hours to help others who might have the problem. I can't right now because my rep

Comment: Yep, problem with webrat. I should have read the error message closer.