# Rails acceptance test: how do you verify the contents of the title tag with minitest-capybara?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, minitest

I just updated a rails app to rails 3.2.11 which broke my (very basic) acceptance tests. A test which used to verify the contents of the `title` tag using

```
page.html.must_have_content(title_text)
```

It turned out that the page still has the title, but the `page` object does not provide it anymore. The following passes now:

```
visit Refinery::railtie_routes_url_helpers.root_path
title_text = "Tischtennisverband des Kantons Zürich"
page.html.must_have_content(title_text)
page.wont_have_content(title_text)
within "title" do
  page.wont_have_content(title_text)
end
```

so the `html` still contains my `title_text`, it still has a `title` tag (otherwise `within` would fail), but there is no contents to that tag anymore. Am I missing on a better way to test the content of `head` (as `page` only seems to contain `body` now) or do 
`minitest-4.4.0`, `capybara-2.0.2` and `nokogiri-1.5.6` (which got picked up during `bundle update`) not play along real nicely?

Comment: Not sure about mini-test, but with RSpec, I created a custom matcher that will hopefully be of reference to you at [this StackOverflow answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13755730/567863).

Comment: Capybara 2.0 [doesn't find invisible texts](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/issues/844)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I test the page title with Capybara 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13573525/how-can-i-test-the-page-title-with-capybara-2-0)