# rails tutorial expected css title with text to return something

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, capybara, railstutorial.org

I am working through the RoR tutorial at ruby.railstutorial.org and am currently on chapter 4.  The tests aren't validating and I have no idea why.
Top part of my spec file looks like this.  The other methods all look identical to Help:

```
describe "StaticPages" do
 let(:page_title) {"Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App"}
 let(:h1_test) {"should have the h1"}
 let(:title_test) {"should have the title"}
 describe "Home page" do |title_test, h1_test|
  it "#{h1_test} 'Sample App'" do
   visit '/static_pages/home'
   page.should have_selector('h1',:text=>'Sample App')
  end

  it "#{title_test} 'Home'" do
   visit '/static_pages/home'
   page.should have_selector('title', :text=> '#{page_title}')
  end

  it "should not have a custom page title" do
   visit '/static_pages/home'
   page.should_not have_selector('title', :text=> '| Home')
  end
end

describe "Help page" do |title_test, h1_test|
 it "#{h1_test} 'Help'" do
  visit '/static_pages/help'
  page.should have_selector('h1', :text =>'Help')
 end

 it "#{title_test} 'Help'" do
  visit '/static_pages/help'
  page.should have_selector('title',
    :text=>'#{page_title} | Help')
 end
end
```

My application_helper.rb:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def full_title(page_title)
    base_title = "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App"
  if page_title.empty?
    base_title
  else
    "#{base_title} | #{page_title}"
    end
  end
end
```

My application.html.haml file:

```
!!!
%html
  %head
    %title= full_title(yield(:title))
    = stylesheet_link_tag "application", :media => "all"
    = javascript_include_tag "application"
    = csrf_meta_tags
  %body= yield
```

Now the 4 errors are identical minus one word change, so I'll just post one:

```
  1) StaticPages Contact#<Class:0x0000000446e818> 'Contact'
     Failure/Error: page.should have_selector('title', :text=>'#{page_title} | Contact')
       expected css "title" with text "\#{page_title} | Contact" to return something
     # ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:65:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I am mystified because I am just copying it straight from the guide other than using haml and adding in those top few lines in my spec file to minimize repeat text. I didn't include the page html files because I can't see how they could be the problem.  Especially since the home.html.haml doesn't have a `- provide(:title, 'Home')` like the others but is still throwing the same error as above.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: Here is my Gemfile:

```
  gem 'rails',       '3.2.12'
  gem 'haml',        '4.0.0'
group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3',     '1.3.5'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.11.0'
  gem 'haml-rails',  '0.4'
  gem 'guard-rspec', '1.2.1'
  gem 'guard-spork', '1.4.2'
  gem 'spork',       '0.9.2'
end
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',  '3.2.5'
  gem 'coffee-rails','3.2.2'
  gem 'uglifier',    '1.2.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails',  '2.0.2'

group :test do
  gem 'capybara',    '1.1.2'
  gem 'rb-inotify',  '0.8.8'
  gem 'libnotify',   '0.5.9'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg',          '0.12.2'
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem.  Where I say `'#{page_title}'` it should be `"#{page_title}"`.  Double quotes instead of single quotes -_-.   Can someone tell me why that works?  Especially because I have stuff like `'Sample App'` in the same have_selector checks and that doesn't throw any kind of error.  Hope this helps someone in the future at least.

Comment: Double quotes are used for string interpolation:http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interpolation#Ruby

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you are using `Capybara` version `1.*` (as used in the tutorial). New versions of `Capybara`, starting from `2.0`, change the way it checks page content. Now construction

```
page.should have_selector(selector, :text=> text)
```

works only for visible DOM elements (`h1`, `p`, `span`, etc.), but does not work for non-visible elements like `title` or `script`.

You can set previous `Capybara` version in the `Gemfile`

```
group :test do
  gem 'capybara', '1.1.2'
end
```

Or modify your tests:

```
page.source.should have_selector(selector, :text=> text)
```

Comment: That is indeed what I have.  I will edit the initial post to incdule my Gemfile.  There was one version number that I did update because the one he suggested gave me errors and I found someone online with the same problem that fixed it with an update.  I don't remember which it was, but it wasn't capybara.  Also, just for kicks I updated capybara to the latest and moved the spec file into spec/features as 2.0 suggests and it still didn't recognize the visit command and so failed all of my tests.  Currently its back to the way it was.

Comment: Ahh yeah I forgot to change the watch path in my guardfile for capybara, so that is why 2.0 failed all the tests.  Still doesn't explain my errors though.  I don't know if it is relevant, but I could post my guardfile as well if you'd like.

Comment: New syntax has changed to `expect(page).to have_selector(selector, text: text)`

Comment: You can match non-visible elements using Capybara 2.x by passing `:visible => false`.  `page.should have_selector(selector, :text => text, :visible => false` will match hidden elements.