# Ruby on Rails tutorial: RSpec test failing when refactoring with matcher

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, railstutorial.org

I'm working through [Michael Hartl's Rails tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/sign-in-sign-out#sec-rspec_custom_matchers) and can't get one Rspec test to pass when refactoring with a matcher.

**terminal output**

```
Failures:

  1) Authentication login with invalid information
     Failure/Error: it { should have_error_message('Invalid') }
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `has_error_message?' for #<Capybara::Session>
     # ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:21:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

**spec/support/utilities.rb**

```
RSpec::Matchers.define :have_error_message do |m|
  match do |page|
    page.should have_selector('div.alert.alert-error', text: m)
  end
end
```

**spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb**

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Authentication" do 

  subject { page }

  describe "login page" do
    before { visit login_path }

    it { should have_selector('h1',    text: 'Login') }
    it { should have_selector('title', text: 'Login') }
  end

  describe "login" do
    before { visit login_path }

    describe "with invalid information" do
      before { click_button "Login" }

      it { should have_selector('title', text: 'Login') }
      it { should have_error_message('Invalid') }
    end

    describe "after visiting after page" do
      before { click_link "Home" }
      it { should_not have_selector('div.alert.alert-error') }
    end

    describe "with valid information" do
      let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
      before { valid_login(user) }

      it { should have_selector('title', text: user.name) }
      it { should have_link('Profile', href: user_path(user)) }
      it { should have_link('Logout', href: logout_path) }
      it { should_not have_link('Login', href: login_path) }

      describe "followed by logout" do
        before { click_link "Logout" }

        it { should have_link('Login') }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Why is it complaining about a `has_error_message?` method that's not defined anywhere?

### Edited/added:

**spec/spec_helper.rb**

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'spork'
#uncomment the following line to use spork with the debugger
#require 'spork/ext/ruby-debug'

Spork.prefork do
  # Loading more in this block will cause your tests to run faster. However,
  # if you change any configuration or code from libraries loaded here, you'll
  # need to restart spork for it take effect.
  ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
  require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
  require 'rspec/rails'
  require 'rspec/autorun'

  # Requires supporting ruby files with custom matchers and macros, etc,
  # in spec/support/ and its subdirectories.
  Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}

  RSpec.configure do |config|
    # ## Mock Framework
    #
    # If you prefer to use mocha, flexmock or RR, uncomment the appropriate line:
    #
    # config.mock_with :mocha
    # config.mock_with :flexmock
    # config.mock_with :rr
    config.mock_with :rspec

    # Remove this line if you're not using ActiveRecord or ActiveRecord fixtures
    config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"

    # If you're not using ActiveRecord, or you'd prefer not to run each of your
    # examples within a transaction, remove the following line or assign false
    # instead of true.
    config.use_transactional_fixtures = true

    # If true, the base class of anonymous controllers will be inferred
    # automatically. This will be the default behavior in future versions of
    # rspec-rails.
    config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = false
  end
end

Spork.each_run do
  # This code will be run each time you run your specs.

end
```

Comment: Can you also post your `spec/spec_helper.rb` file?

Comment: It's updated now! @StuartM

Comment: Note - problem proved to be some copy/paste weirdness (I had identical problem) - see comments on accepted answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you `require`'ing your `spec/support/utilities.rb` file? You may need something like this in your `spec/spec_helper.rb` file to actually load the file where you define the custom matcher:

```
Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}
```

**Update:** If you're using Spork, your `utilities.rb` file may be getting cached by the Spork server, meaning you would need to restart your master Spork process before the new matcher could be used by RSpec ([see details](https://github.com/sporkrb/spork/wiki/Troubleshooting#some-changes-to-files-dont-take-effect-until-i-restart-spork) on the Spork wiki).

[Some people](https://github.com/sporkrb/spork/wiki/Spork.trap_method-Jujitsu#machinist) use this trick to force Spork to always reload support files:

```
Spork.each_run do
  Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}
end
```

Comment: It seems like I do have that line in my spec file, so that's not causing the problem, especially since the `valid_login` method I have in the same `utilities.rb` file is working just fine.

Comment: Can you test whether your custom matcher is actually being used? Try putting a `raise RuntimeError` right before `page.should have_selector...` and if it does not raise an error, it might indicate your matcher isn't getting registered with RSpec properly somehow

Comment: Also, have you restarted your Spork server after writing this new matcher? See my update to the answer above for another possibility related to Spork

Comment: I don't have Spork running and it still raises the error; I tried adding the `RuntimeError` and it looks like the matcher does get run: `Failures:

  1) Authentication login with invalid information
     Failure/Error: it { should have_error_message('Invalid') }
     RuntimeError:
       RuntimeError
     # ./spec/support/utilities.rb:11:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:21:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'`

Comment: What version of Capybara are you using? Might this be the same thing as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13573525/rspec-capybara-2-0-tripping-up-my-have-selector-tests ?

Comment: It seems like its trying to use the [built-in matcher](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs/built-in-matchers) `actual.should have_xxx(:arg) # passes if actual.has_xxx?(:arg)`. What happens if you rename the matcher to something else that doesn't begin with `have_` ?

Comment: Okay, for some freak reason I decided to recopy the methods from the tutorial site... and this time it worked. That `has_error_message?` error is going to haunt me for a long time. In any case, thanks so much for the help- I'm going to accept this as the answer.

Comment: I had the same problem, and recopying the methods worked for me to... Inspected pasted content with a binary editor to look for non-printing character weirdness but couldn't find any...

Answer (score 2):

If you're using a later version of Capybara or RSpec (ie not the ones explicitly specified in the tutorial), if I recall correctly the way that those custom matchers needed to be written changed (though I could be wrong about that)  Nevertheless, try changing your method from

```
RSpec::Matchers.define :have_error_message do |m|
  match do |page|
    page.should have_selector('div.alert.alert-error', text: m)
  end
end
```

to:

```
RSpec::Matchers.define :have_error_message do |m|
  match do |page|
    page.has_selector?('div.alert.alert-error', text: m)
  end
end
```

This will then hopefully enable you to write tests like:

```
it { should have_error_message("Invalid") }
it { should_not have_error_message("Invalid") }
```

I had a similar issue that I outlined in [this StackOverflow Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13573525/567863).

Comment: Ah, this wasn't my problem as I was using v1.1.2 of Capybara, but I'm sure I'll upgrade the gem at some point in the future, so this is super helpful to know. Thanks!