# Rspec let variable not working with have_title

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I'm having trouble getting one of my Rspec tests to pass using Capybara 2.1.0

This works:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Static pages" do

  describe "Home page" do

      it "should have the title 'Home'" do
      visit '/static_pages/home'
      page.should have_title("MyApp | Home")
    end
  end
end
```

This does not

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Static pages" do

  let(:site_title) {"MyApp"}

  describe "Home page" do

      it "should have the title 'Home'" do
      visit '/static_pages/home'
      page.should have_title("#{site_title} | Home")
    end
  end
end
```

Any thoughts? I've been working on it for quite a while. Here is the error message that I receive.

```
1) Static pages Home page should haven the title
 Failure/Error: page.should have_title("#{site_title} | Home")
   expected #has_title?("MyApp | Home") to return true, got false
 # ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:16:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Comment: Could you edit your question to include the error message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you are missing the curly braces for `#{site_title}` or you need to use double quotes for your string to allow interpolation of variables.  You have:

```
page.should have_title('#site_title | Home')
```

where it should be

```
page.should have_title("#{site_title} | Home")
```

Comment: I do have the curly brackets in my code. Not sure why it doesn't show in the error message. I tried switching to double quotes and it didn't work either.

Comment: It's likely RSpec is reading outdated code.  It may seem obvious, but did you save your changes before you ran your tests and/or restart any continuous development tools like Spork you may be using?

Comment: Thank you, I forgot to restart guard/spork. When I did it showed the curly brackets in the error but still failed. Expected it to return true etc...

Comment: Would you be able to update the error message in your question then, please?

Comment: Move the `#` to before the `{` and that should make the test pass.  Or just copy and paste the line `page.should have_title("#{site_title} | Home")`.

Comment: Thanks for your patience with this. I updated the code and it looks like we are making progress but it still fails. I updated the error. If I use the string "MyApp | Home" it passes.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30453/discussion-between-paul-fioravanti-and-fajitanachos)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Static pages" do

  let(:site_title) {"MyApp"}

  describe "Home page" do

      it "should have the title 'Home'" do
      visit '/static_pages/home'
      page.should have_selector('title', text: "#{site_title} | Home")
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, but the have_selector doesn't work with the version of Capybara I'm using. I think it doesn't work in anything over 2.0 unless I'm mistaken. That's why I'm using have_title per this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13573525/rspec-capybara-2-0-tripping-up-my-have-selector-tests