# Chapter 5 - Ruby on Rails Tutorial - undefined method `has_title?' when running RSpec tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

Just trying to get through the last bit of chapter 5 in Michael Hartl's Ruby on Rails Tutorial and getting another error running RSpec tests.

The output is :

> Static pages should have the right links on the layout
>       Failure/Error: expect(page).to have_title('About Us')
>       NoMethodError:
>         undefined method `has_title?' for #<Capybara::Session>
>       # ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:59:in`block (2 levels) in '

and results from the line starting **expect(page)** in the following code in **static_pages_spec.rb** :

```
it "should have the right links on the layout" do
    visit root_path
    click_link "About"
   expect(page).to have_title(full_title('About Us'))
end
```

Note : This happens running with or without Spork

Can anyone point me in the right direction please ?

Thanks,
Bazza

Answer (score 7):

The `have_title` function is supported from Capybara 2.1. I suppose you have an older version of Capybara in your Gemfile. So, update your Gemfile with

```
gem 'capybara', '2.1.0'
```

then update  Capybara like this

```
bundle update capybara
```

and rerun the specs using rspec. It should work now

Refer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13573525/rspec-capybara-2-0-tripping-up-my-have-selector-tests) for other options