# Rspec/Rails3: NoMethodError: undefined method `text' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, testing, rspec

I've got some tests failing. The following are my tests:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Authenticaton" do

  let(:base_title){"KS > Kids | "}

  subject { page }

  describe "for non-signed-in users" do

    let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
    let(:subject) { FactoryGirl.create(:subject) }

    context "in the Subjects controller" do

      describe "visiting the edit page" do
        before { visit edit_subject_path(subject) }
        it { should have_title("#{base_title}Home") }
      end 

      describe "visiting the subject index" do
        before { visit subjects_path }
        it { should have_title("#{base_title}Home") } 
      end 

    end 
  end 
end
```

And this is output

1) Authenticaton for non-signed-in users in the Subjects controller visiting the subject index

```
 Failure/Error: it { should have_title("#{base_title}#{I18n.t("messages.session.sign_in")}") }
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `text' for nil:NilClass
 # ./spec/requests/extra_auth_pages_spec.rb:23:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

2) Authenticaton for non-signed-in users in the Subjects controller visiting the edit page

```
 Failure/Error: it { should have_title("#{base_title}Home") }
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `text' for nil:NilClass
 # ./spec/requests/extra_auth_pages_spec.rb:18:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I'm missing something here?  Thanks for your help!

Comment: No evaluation can be made unless we know what code calls `.text`

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13573525/rspec-capybara-2-0-tripping-up-my-have-selector-tests

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to know without seeing the code under test, but there are a couple of potential causes:

1) Remember that `let` is lazy-evaluated: `let` does not create objects until the symbol is referenced in the spec. For this case, you may expect that the `user` instance is created before the `visit` occurs, but it won't exist because `user` is never evaluated. That will likely cause an authentication failure.

2) `subject` is an unfortunate choice of names, since RSpec uses `subject` to refer to the object instance being tested. This may or may not cause a problem.

Comment: Thank you very much, my problem was name clash with subject in RSpec. I changed the variable name in let to something else, everything worked well.

Answer (score 0):

### For the interest of future reference

I had the same problem, which was because **some manually defined fixtures violated a uniqueness constraint in the model.** I'm guessing this caused the fixtures to not be loaded correctly into the test database.

The test lines which failed were (I'm using RSpec):

```rb
it "should expect some value" do
    fixture_item = manual_fixture_table('fixture_item_label')
    expect (fixture_item).to be_valid    #This line was failing
    #[...]
end
```

The error I got was:

```
Failure/Error: expect(fixture_item).to be_valid
     
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `text?' for nil:NilClass
```

By fixing this (in my case, by removing the uniqueness constraint which was unnecessary) this error was solved.