# ActionController::TestResponse does not respond to method has_selector?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, railstutorial.org, ruby-2.0, rspec3

I'm following the older version (for Rails 3) of Michael Hartl's Rails screencasts. However, I'm using Ruby 2 with Rails 4 (`rspec-rails` 3.0.1), interpolating between the lessons and practice via Google searches.

I'm stuck with a possibly wrong matcher. Here is my failing spec:

```
RSpec.describe PagesController do
  render_views

    it "has the correct page title" do
      get 'home'
      expect(response).to have_selector('title')
    end
  end

end
```

Here's the error message:

```
Failures:

  1) PagesController GET 'home' has the correct page title
     Failure/Error: expect(response).to have_selector('title')
       expected #<ActionController::TestResponse:0x9e1202c> to respond to `has_selector?`
     # ./spec/controllers/pages_controller_spec.rb:13:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # -e:1:in `<main>'
```

It seems that there is no such matcher as have_selector in `rspec-rails3`. I've looked it up on [their Github page](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails) there seems to be no mention of this matcher.

`Gemfile`:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org' 
ruby '2.0.0'

gem 'rails', '4.0.0'
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder'

group :doc do
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end

group :development do
  gem 'spring-commands-rspec'
end

group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec'
  gem 'rspec-rails'
end
```

Comment: @DaveSchweisguth, thanks for the edits. I'll keep those in mind for furture posts!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `have_selector` matcher is provided by Capybara. Add that to your Gemfile.

Comment: Thanks, that fixes it. Now I can move on to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13573525/