# Testing page title with Capybara 2.4 and rspec 3 and rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, capybara

I am trying to test the title of my static pages in rails. I'm using Capybara 2.4.4 and rspec 3.

My test looks like the following
**static_pages_controller_spec.rb**

```
require 'spec_helper'
require 'rails_helper'
describe StaticPagesController do
  describe "GET 'Index'" do
    it "should be successful" do 
      visit root_path
      response.should be_success
    end

    it "should have the right title" do
      visit root_path
      expect(page).to have_selector('title', 
                     :text => "Index",
                     :visible => false)
    end 
  end
end
```

The page does have the correct title set. 
The error I'm getting says the following

```
Failure/Error: expect(page).to have_selector('title',
       expected to find css "title" with text "Index" but there were no matches
```

Comment: you should expect page(page).to have_content instead

Comment: Perhaps post the view code?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13573525/rspec-capybara-2-0-tripping-up-my-have-selector-tests

This should have your answer.

Comment: @trueinViso I tried the most updated answer and am receiving expected "" to include "Index" error

Comment: You tried `expect(page).to have_title "Index"`? And you have `<title>Index<\title>` on the page you are testing?  And just to make sure you did `save_and_open_page` in your test and inspected the element to make sure that html is there?

Comment: I noticed you put visit root_path, is root path the path to this controller method/view?

Answer (score 0):

I spent quite a few hours trying to figure it out as well.

Ultimately what worked was this

Install capybara as a gem

```
group :test do
  gem 'rspec'
  gem 'capybara'
end
```

and run `bundle install`

Add the following to the top of spec/spec_helper.rb

```
require 'capybara/rails'
require 'capybara/rspec'
```

Then inside the RSpec.configure, add the `config.include Capybara::DSL`

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  .
  .
  .
  config.include Capybara::DSL
end
```

Then in your `pages_controller_spec.rb`, modify to use as follows.

Notice that I have included `Capybara.ignore_hidden_elements = false`

```
describe PagesController do
  render_views
  Capybara.ignore_hidden_elements = false

  describe "GET 'home'" do
    it "should be successful" do
      get 'home'
      response.should be_success
    end
    it "should have the right title" do
      get 'home'
      response.body.should have_xpath("//title",:text => "ROR")
    end
  end

end
```

[Check my repository](https://github.com/Ranhiru/ruby_blog/tree/static-pages) if you want see anything else

The following cheatsheet should come handy as well
https://gist.github.com/them0nk/2166525

Comment: My apologies for not coming back to this sooner. I just tried to implement your solution and it still isn't working. I am receiving "expected to find xpath "//title" with text "TITLE" but there were no matches".