# Test title with rspec in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec, title

Starting up with this:

```
it "doit avoir le bon titre" do
  get 'home'
  response.should have_selector("title", :content => "Simple App du Tutoriel Ruby on Rails | Accueil")
end
```

I ended up with that because I'm not on the same version of rspec or rails than the tutorial I'm following:

```
it "doit avoir le bon titre" do
    get 'home'
    expect(response).to have_selector("title", :text => "Simple App du Tutoriel Ruby on Rails | Accueil")
end
```

And now it's telling me this

```
Failure/Error: expect(response).to have_selector("title", :text => "Simple App du Tutoriel Ruby on Rails | Accueil")
       expected to find css "title" with text "Simple App du Tutoriel Ruby on Rails | Accueil" but there were no matches
```

Why is it talking about CSS when all I want to do is validate the title? Am I doing it right considering I wanna do what the first sample of code is doing?

Obviously not because I have an error but what am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13573525/rspec-capybara-2-0-tripping-up-my-have-selector-tests

Comment: have_selector() => search 'css selectors'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right syntax was:

```
it "doit avoir le bon titre" do
  get :home
  expect(response.body).to have_title('Simple App du Tutoriel Ruby on Rails | Accueil')
end
```

Partly solved thanks to Siekfried and his link: [How can I test the page title with Capybara 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13573525/rspec-capybara-2-0-tripping-up-my-have-selector-tests)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tryed :

```
    it "doit avoir le bon titre" do
      get :home
      expect(response.body).to include('<title>My Title</title>')
    end
  end
```

??

Comment: Won't I need to always adapt my spec to fit my <title> attribut? As if I change id or add class?